# Is there a more accurate way to see if two sprites intersect?

Tags: objective-c, sprite, sprite-kit, cgrect, skscene

```
CGRect rect4 = CGRectMake(rock.position.x, rock.position.y, rock.size.width, rock.size.height);
CGRect bulletRect = CGRectMake(bullet.position.x, bullet.position.y, bullet.size.width, bullet.size.height);
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(bulletRect, rect4)) {
    NSLog(@"hit Bullet");
    //[bullet removeFromParent];
}
```

It seems to "Hit the Bullet" even if the rect 4 is no where near the bullet.
Thank you

Comment: We need more information. Is the bullet and the rock in the same coordinate system (node)? How does the bullet and the rock look like?

Comment: The rock is not a perfect box shape but is an irregular polygon shape

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how your shapes look like, but my guess is that their are only loosly symbolized by a rectangle.

-First check that your x and y rock and bullet positions are really their upper left corner coordinates, if not consider a translation of your bounding rectangle.

-To increase the precision of the bounding shape, without getting too complicated you could use a cloud of points that are situated on the boarder of the less rectangular of your object. Then you would use `CGRectContainsPoint` to check if the shapes intersect. You should position your points on the most prominent part of the polygon boarder. You could get their coordinate relatively to the rock.position.x and y coordinates.

For example: you know your rock's x and y. You can situate a point with something like: p1 = x+dx, y+dy.

[image]

Note that here, in the case where there is no intersection, a typical bounding box approach would have considered it an intersection.

So, in code:

```
CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(rock.position.x+dx, rock.position.y+dy);
CGRect bulletRect = CGRectMake(bullet.position.x, bullet.position.y, bullet.size.width, bullet.size.height);
if (CGRectContainsPoint(bulletRect, p1)) {
    NSLog(@"hit Bullet");
}
```

Of course, the more points you have, the more precise it will be. Just loop over a point array and `break` if you have a true.

Another option, much more complicated and accurate, could be a graphic engine such as [Box2D](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/setup-ios)

Hope it helped.

F

---

EDIT

---

Dx and Dy are the differences between your known point (rock.position.x, rock.position.y) and the point to test (p1 here).

[image: dx and dy]

Comment: Wow.. Thank you Very Much for taking the time to do this! One question, what is "dx and dy"?